# Where does Feedly and Feedbin get their feed favicon icons from?

Tags: rss, favicon, rss-reader, feedly

I'm looking at the API for Feedbin (https://github.com/feedbin/feedbin-api/blob/master/content/subscriptions.md) and I can't seem to find where I can retrieve the favicon for the feed.

Does anyone know how this is usually requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code, it seems to be coming from [Cloudfront](https://github.com/feedbin/feedbin/blob/master/app/presenters/base_presenter.rb#L26). Now, that probably does not answer your question as to how it ends up there. 
In all likely hood Feedbin or Feedly use a library that extract the favicon url based on the HTML pages related to a feed.

Comment: Thanks I got it working using the CloudFront server. I'm guessing it's some sort of caching service that was written.

Answer (score 0):

For feedbin, this can solve the question
https://api.feedbin.com/v2/icons.json
It shows all icons for feeds that the user is subscribed to.
[Feedbin GitHub - Icons](https://github.com/feedbin/feedbin-api/blob/master/content/icons.md)